# Why subdomains of Blogspot/WordPress like sites are treated as different domains or sites?

Tags: domains, subdomain, multi-subdomains

As I know, `maps.google.com` or `mail.google.com` all comes under the same domain and its all are subdomain. Entire web treats these subdomain as the part of main domain and they have same Alexa rank, PageRank and all.

But in another hand, take a look on `blogspot.com`/`wordpress.com`/`webs.com`; these are different sites but blogs or websites under those domains are treated as different sites.
Its new URL, all have different PageRank and Alexa rank as well.

Tts about millions of subdomains under those few domain, have almost similar IP address, hosting and CMS, still why they are called different domains?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers. After few more research about SEO, I came up with fact that, PageRank is not same for a site, but its depend upon the particular one page.
either have example of Facebook.

Facebook home page will have PR9 and other pages on FB will have different PR.
Thank you to tutorial I found online, unable to mention name here, but I can show you screenshot of PR for different pages of FB having different PR.

[image]

and PR for one of the Facebook page is 2.
[image]

Comment: Of course PageRank is per page and not per site.

Answer (score 0):

All subdomains of `google.com` are treated separately by Google like for WordPress, Blogspot subdomains. Moreover, Alexa rank is different for Google Maps and Gmail. These two websites are a PageRank of 9 because there are famous websites but it doesn't mean they are treated as the part of main domain.

Search engines are obliged to treat subdomains as a different domains because a subdomain can't use popularity of main domain for just a new little blog on cooking (for example).

Comment: I completely agree that but, this is not only for blogspot or wordpress, there are bunch of other sites too, isn't it so partial for specific site's sub domain will be treated as different domains in all aspact?

Comment: Google has no choice and must treat ALL subdomains as different domains (whatever the platform).

Answer (score 0):

Google has to have implemented algorithms that try to guess whether all the subdomains of a site are controlled by the same entity.  For most websites, there are going to be few subdomains, and the subdomains will all be run by the same person or organization.  There will be a relatively small number of sites like wordpress.com that allow users to each control a subdomain.

Once search engines identify domains that allow users to edit an entire subdomain, they will treat them differently in their algorithms.